# A standard partial differenciation question where Z is a function of x and y

Tags: calculus

If $x^xy^yz^z = c$, show that at $x = y = z, z_{xy} = -(x\log x)^{-1}$

I applied logarithmic functions on both sides, ultimately it led to a satisfying result where most things canceled out, but unfortunately, it wasn't the right answer.

My final answer was: $$\frac{-2(1+\log x)^{-1}}{x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking logarithms of both sides and differentiating wrt $x$ gives $$\log x + 1+ z_x\log z + z_x=0.$$ Now differentiate wrt $y$ to get $$z_{xy}\log z+z_x\frac{1}{z}z_y+z_{xy}=0.$$

From the first equation you can solve for $z_x$ and substitute in the second equation. Finally, differentiating the original equation (after taking logs of course) now wrt $y,$ we get $$\log y + 1+ z_y\log z + z_y=0,$$ from which again you may solve for $z_y$ and substitute in the equation for $z_{xy}.$ Then finally you may express $z_{xy}$ explicitly in terms of $x,y,z.$ Finally, set $x=y=z,$ and you'd have been done.

Or, more expeditiously, note that when $x=y=z,$ we have $z_x=z_y=-1.$ This gives $$z_{xy}=-\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+\log x},$$ so that your result is closer to the truth than the book's. I suspect there was a mistyping by the book makers.